# Sequelize Single Instance - Not working after Module.exports

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this Sequelize Code for connecting to my database

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db-name', 'user', 'pwd', {
    host: 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX',
    dialect: 'mysql',

    pool: {
        max: 50,
        min: 0,
        idle: 1000000
    },
});
```

I have wrapped this in a module like below

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');


module.exports = function (Sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return new Sequelize('db-name', 'user', 'pwd', {
        host: 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        pool: {
            max: 50,
            min: 0,
            idle: 1000000
        },
    });
};
```

However ,when I call this code below:

```
var sequelize = require('../../Connection.js');
//load model
var City = sequelize.import('../../models/City.js');
```

It gives me an error saying - undefined is not a function.Basically it is not able to instantiate the sequelize object when I am importing the module

However everything works fine when I am putting these blocks in one page

My core requirement - I want a single connection object across my node app. I have modularized Express Routes in various page.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequelize module exports a function, which returns sequelize. You have to actually call that function

```
var sequelize = require('../../Connection.js')() <-- ;
```

Remember to cache the instance in connection.js - otherwise you get a new connection each time. You can also export the instance directly:

```
module.exports = new Sequelize('db-name', 'user', 'pwd', {
    host: 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    pool: {
        max: 50,
        min: 0,
        idle: 1000000
    },
});
```